# Can't find stored procedure parameters in code-behind

Tags: c#, code-behind

The Overview: I've got a dropdown with a list of reports the user can run. In the table that holds this list, I have ReportID, ReportName, SProc and SQLView fields. The idea here is, the user selects a report name, and based on that a specific Stored Procedure will run, and then a specific view will be bound to a datagrid to display the report.  For some reports you need to enter a date, for others you don't.

The Code: Here is what I have written;

```
    protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ReportData> myReportData = new List<ReportData>();
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(str2))
        {
            //Query the Reports table to find the record associated with the selected report
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblManagerReports WHERE ReportID =  " + cboFilterOption.SelectedValue + "", connection1))
            {
                connection1.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader DT1 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (DT1.Read())
                    {
                        //Read the record into an "array", so you can find the SProc and View names
                        int MyRptID = Convert.ToInt32(DT1[0]);
                        string MyRptName = DT1[1].ToString();
                        string MyRptSproc = DT1[2].ToString();
                        string MySQLView = DT1[3].ToString();

                        //Run the Stored Procedure first
                        SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(str2);
                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("" + MyRptSproc + "", connection2);

                        //Set up the parameters, if they exist
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtStartDate.Text))
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@StDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtStartDate.Text;
                        }

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtEndDate.Text))
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EnDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtEndDate.Text;
                        }

                            if (MyRptSproc != "")
                            {
                                connection2.Open();
                                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                                try
                                {
                                    //Now open the View and bind it to the GridView
                                    string SelectView = "SELECT * FROM " + MySQLView + "";
                                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str2);
                                    SqlCommand SelectCmd = new SqlCommand(SelectView, con);
                                    SqlDataAdapter SelectAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCmd);

                                    //Fill the dataset
                                    DataSet RunReport = new DataSet();
                                    SelectAdapter.Fill(RunReport);

                                    GridView_Reports.DataSource = RunReport;
                                    GridView_Reports.DataBind();
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSubmit, typeof(Button), "Report Menu", "alert('There is no View associated with this report.\\nPlease contact the developers and let them know of this issue.')", true);
                                    return;
                                }        

                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

The Problem: When the code hits the line

> cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

and there is a start and end date entered, it's telling me "Procedure or function  expects parameter '@StDate', which is not supplied."  I've stepped through the code and see that cmd2 has 2 parameters, so why isn't the function seeing them?

Additionally, here's the specific stored procedure which is causing the snafu (I've got 2 others that run fine, but neither of them are trying to pass parameters to a stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_DailyProc]
    @StDate smalldatetime,
    @EnDate smalldatetime
AS

BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_DailyProduction') IS NOT NULL 
    drop table Temp_DailyProduction;

IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_AuditorDailyProduction') IS NOT NULL 
    drop table Temp_AuditorDailyProduction;    

SELECT 
    [Audit Date],
    Auditor,
    Count([Doc #]) AS [Claim Count],
    Count([Primary Error Code]) AS [Final Error],
    SUM(case when [Status]='removed' then 1 else 0 end) as Removed, 
    SOCNUM
INTO Temp_DailyProc
FROM PreClosed
WHERE (((Get_Next_Status)='Closed' Or (Get_Next_Status)='Panel' Or (Get_Next_Status)='HPanel'))
GROUP BY [Audit Date], Auditor, SOCNUM
HAVING ((([Audit Date]) Between @StDate And @EnDate));  

SELECT 
    TDP.[Audit Date], 
    TDP.Auditor, 
    EID.EMPLOYEE AS [Auditor Name], 
    TDP.[Claim Count], 
    TDP.[Final Error], 
    TDP.Removed, 
    TDP.[Removed]/TDP.[Final Error] AS [Error Removal Ratio], 
    TDP.SOCNUM
INTO Temp_AuditorDailyProc  
FROM Temp_DailyProc TDP 
LEFT JOIN PreLookup EID
    ON TDP.Auditor = EID.ID_Trim;

drop table Temp_DailyProduction;

END
```

Comment: FYI, it looks like you have a SQL injection vulnerability in there.

Comment: Yeah, but we're not really worried because it's an Intranet.  Just trying to get the darn thing to work.  If we need to circle back later, we'll tidy it up.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you need to use the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method instead of the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> AddWithValue replaces the SqlParameterCollection.Add method that takes
>   a String and an Object. The overload of Add that takes a string and an
>   object was deprecated because of possible ambiguity with the
>   SqlParameterCollection.Add overload that takes a String and a
>   SqlDbType enumeration value where passing an integer with the string
>   could be interpreted as being either the parameter value or the
>   corresponding SqlDbType value. Use AddWithValue whenever you want to
>   add a parameter by specifying its name and value.

Had another thought, you are passing a string (Text) value as Date parameter. I think you should convert this to a date type. e.g.

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@StDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
```

A more robust way of doing this would be to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Didn't work.  Am I using ExecuteNonQuery properly?  I'm trying to run a stored procedure that creates a table, I don't actually want anything returned and most of the sample code I've seen that uses it seems to be looking for some value to return.

Comment: I can't see any obvious problem there, could you perhaps post the stored proc code?

Comment: I added it to my original post.

Comment: Yes.  My issue turned out to be that I needed to add a line setting the CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure.  I'm gonna give you a +1 for jumping in and helping.  I appreciate it!